# What is file input format for Recommendation Engine?

Tags: mahout, recommendation-engine, mahout-recommender

I am using Ubuntu12.04, Hadoop-1.0.4, Mahout-0.7 running job on Hadoop cluster for Recommendation algorithm when I am giving input file in this format, map reduce runs fine but not giving any result(blank)

tataRecommend100.txt (userID - productID - preference)

```
14218954    54518   4
14218954    617691  2
14218954    616488  2
14218954    614975  2
14218954    605662  1
14218954    619979  1
14218954    14183   3
14218954    611309  5
14218954    615242  3
14218954    13138   1
14232708    54518   1
14232708    617691  3
14232708    616488  1
14232708    614975  5
14232708    605662  4
```

command :-`bin/hadoop jar /home/hadoop/apacheC/mahout-distribution-0.7/mahout-core-0.7-job.jar

org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.item.RecommenderJob  -s  SIMILARITY_COOCCURRENCE --input /tataDocomo/recommend/tataRecommend100.txt --output /tataDocomo/recommend/tataRecommendOutput`

Comment: Are you sure about your code?

Comment: @Tariq,yes I am sure code works fine when I used GroupLensdata (http://www.grouplens.org/system/files/ml-100k.zip),u.data file.Same structure I used here also,but not working

Answer (score 0):

Your data is simply too sparse / small to make recommendations. Try with a non-toy data set.

Comment: due to space limitation i am showing only 20 rows,but I m running on 10000 ratings(rows) having different values.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you haven't given it a user id for whom you want recommendations? That happened to me when I was giving it a try the first time. No output. You drop this in the file you pass in for --userFile.